# Enlightened badge clarification

Tags: discussion, support, badges

For the `first answer criterion` for the Enlightened badge, is the first answer the one

- that remains, excluding deleted answers; or
- that ever was, including deleted answers

As for the suggestion, if it were the latter, can we please make it the former?  It would make sense to exclude squatters from the equation if they later retract their answer from the question (having reached no good solution).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the former.

I have received the badge for an answer that was second, but the first poster deleted their answer. It was on Super User. I'd post the link, but only those with 10K+ rep on SU will be able to see the deleted answer, but it's time stamp was:

> Sep 13 '09 at 20:27

whereas my answer was posted at:

> Sep 13 '09 at 20:28

one second later.

Comment: That must have been a great fight.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the case. Another link: (only interpretable for 10k+ users): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python/1885197#1885197

Comment: @cyberwiki - just luck