# Enlightened badge and "recalculation" or not

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enlightened badge clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76603/enlightened-badge-clarification)

I have a question about how a detail of the **[Enlightened badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened)** works.

> **Enlightened badge**: First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes.

What happens if the first answer gets deleted? Does the second answer then count as the first  in regard to the Enlightened badge or is it still marked in the system as second/not first?

Or does some magic "recalculation" happen, so that it is still possible to earn the Enlightened badge on a question which had a deleted answer before?