# Clarification Enlightened badge for own answered question

Tags: support, badges, self-answer, enlightened-badge

I have the situation that I answered one of my own questions on SO. For a while now I have 12 upvotes on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845977/net-implementation-of-scrypt/5278644#5278644) but so far have not earned the [Enlightened badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened) (see [my SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135441/martin-buberl)).

I remember there was one answer before mine, but it got deleted. According to this answer, this shouldn't affect the badge: [Enlightened badge clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76603/enlightened-badge-clarification/76604#76604)

Is this wanted behavior - because I obviously accepted my own answer - to not give the badge in that case, or is it a bug? The [SE blog states it's okay to answer your own questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and for that I wouldn't see any reason it should be treated differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jeff Atwood has [already confirmed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/why-didnt-i-earn-another-enlightened-badge) that self-accepts are not eligible for the "Enlightened" badge.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the enlightened are rewarded for sharing enlightenment with others, i.e., answering another's question.  Your answer to your own question may help others, but only indirectly (if they happen to have the same issue).

Comment: Not getting what you mean by indirectly. Isn't that true for every answer?

Comment: @MartinBuberl An answer on someone else's question solving their problem is about as direct as you can get.